# How to implement unimplemented methods to all child classes in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

As you know, eclipse provides with a nice way to implement unimplemented methods if a child class does not have them implemented. Is there any way to apply this to all child classes?

My problem is that I have to do this for each child class when there are 50 of them. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I suppose, you still have to implement the semantics of the methods of the 50 sub-classes... So you still have to go to all the classes one-by-one... So why bother with this? It even makes it more difficult, as it is harder to know how far you have gotten...

Comment: I have a trick to fill those implementation into 50 methods if they exist. So most work of the task is copying the signature stuff into those files. That's why. And I don't understand your last argument as my tests will let me know how far I've gotten.

Comment: As long as you have not implemented the missing method, the compiler will highlight the missing methods. Which in my book should be faster than finding the missing implementations during testing :-) Good luck with it anyway....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

select the top level package in your package explorer. Go to the 'Problems' view. There should be the list of errors of "The type Foo must implement the inherited abstract method Parent.foo()"  (for given class/method names). Right click on the error, select "Quick Fix". You can select the "Add unimplemented methods" option and click the "Select All Button" to select all the child classes.

EDIT: This works even for multiple methods per parent class.

Comment: many times, I have pondered on using "abstract" or not because of the trouble it causes (going on each file manually), but I was sure eclipse would help on that! thanks on showing how, no more lazy/carpaltunnel decisions concerning this xD

Comment: For Android studio please check the answer @ link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099969/how-to-implement-unimplemented-methods-to-all-child-classes-in-eclipse/42382559#42382559

Answer (score 3):

[Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099969/how-to-implement-unimplemented-methods-to-all-child-classes-in-eclipse) can be solved using "*source/cleanup*" feature, after applying few changes in eclipse as:

1. Make your own project specific profile for Java Code Style/Clean Up:
   Select the *Project/BuildPath/Configure Build Path*> Click on *Java Code Style/Clean Up* > Check *Enable Project Specific Settings/Edit*> Check *Add unimplemented methods* and give *Profile name*.
   [image]

2. Select *Project/Source/Clean Up*, it will show project name and the profile name we created. Click on finish.
[image]

Now method will be added to all child classes:
[image]

*Once profile is created, this works even for multiple methods added in the interface or abstract class. Just follow step 2.*

Answer (score 2):

For Android Studio guys below is the workaround for it,
Add this method in your interface or abstract class,

```
@Override
        public void methodInInterfaceOrAbstract()
        {
            // this must me in interface or abstract class which will be implemented by child classes 
        }
```

Then right click the java file, select the option "Refactor" then select the option "Push members down". Select the method which you want to push down to all child classes and click refactor.
Your new method  added in interface or abstract class will be moved to all child classes.
Now you need to add the declaration of the method in interface or abstract class again as the method was moved to all child classes.