# Adding overrided method in all the classes in one shot

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project in which almost 50 classes extend the same parent class. Now i am adding an abstract method in the parent class. Due to this all the classes generate compile time error.
In this situation, Is there any way to add this method in all the sub classes in one shot in eclipse IDE ?

Comment: How would this be useful? You would still have to provide the correct content...

Comment: You should provide more context and code in order to receive meaningful answers for your question.

Comment: This problem can be easily solve using eclipse ["source/cleanup" feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099969/how-to-implement-unimplemented-methods-to-all-child-classes-in-eclipse/15110880#15110880).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't you need to do something meaningful (and different) in each of those 50 classes? If not, then you should place the implementation in the parent class. If so, then any type of "quick fix all" would be counter-productive in this case. Basically, if eclipse or any other IDE did what you ask, it would basically encourage changing a small programming task into a large test/QA task.

For the record, I think [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14998560/122207) is more elegantly stated.

Comment: @ Tim Bender Obviously i have to do some processing in this method. Adding the logic in all the 50 classes is taking time. What i want is, for time being have an empty implementation of this method in all subclasses to remove compile time error.Then afterwards, i will add the logic one by one.

Comment: I understand what you want. To elaborate on the last sentence of my answer... What you want is **bad!** While the compile errors may be annoying for the moment, the application being worked on is better off not compiling rather than compiling with dozens of simple known issues which will almost certainly result in runtime exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer that Eclipse doesn't support this.

To add to [Tim Bender's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14998303/122207), the reason why such a feature would be counter-productive is that you need to visit all of those classes anyway to add bodies to the methods.  If you were to auto-generate stub methods, the chances are that you would miss one (or more).  So your simple coding task would turn into a more challenging debugging task ... or worse if you don't have decent unit and system test procedures.

Best to add the methods one at a time, and *use* the list of compiler errors to remind you what classes still need to be dealt with.  (I've found myself in situation too ... and this approach *works*.)

Comment: I understood what you say. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

"select the top level package in your package explorer. Go to the 'Problems' view. There should be the list of errors of "The type Foo must implement the inherited abstract method Parent.foo()" (for given class/method names). Right click on the error, select "Quick Fix". You can select the "Add unimplemented methods" option and click the "Select All Button" to select all the child classes.
EDIT: This works even for multiple methods per parent class."
Copied from the link below and it works

[How to implement unimplemented methods to all child classes in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099969/how-to-implement-unimplemented-methods-to-all-child-classes-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a simple method to your parent class

   /** This should be overridden in the parent class!! */
   @Deprecated
   public void foo() { 
   }
2. Implement a method in a subclass. Test the method.
3. Repeat step 2 until method implementation exists in every subclass.
4. Make the original method in the parent class abstract

   public abstract void foo();

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may have some serious design problems if you have 50 different implementations.

If you want to put the same code in all of your classes you should just provide an implementation in your abstract one so the compiler won't complain. Otherwise don't expect Eclipse to know what implementation you are planning to write in all of your classes.

If your method does nothing initially (you can't provide a meaningful implementation of it) you can just do this in your abstract class:

```
void myMethod() {
    // does nothing yet
}
```