# Equivalent of Eclipse's "Problems" view on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I used to code for Android on Eclipse and have become accustomed to the "Problems" view which lists all warnings and errors in the whole project, making it easy to zoom into exactly which line(s) of code were causing issues.

I've since migrated to Android Studio, but I can't seem to find a view that performs a similar function. Instead, the errors are only shown to me when I click into an individual file, which is too much hassle.

Is there an equivalent of the "Problems" view (in Eclipse) for Android Studio?

Answer (score 4):

You can build the projects, then the errors and warnings will display in message panel.

Click on errors/warnings can jump to the code. This can be used as a workaround.

Comment: I guess I got too spoiled by Eclipse's automatic build feature! Guess I'll have to make do with this for now. (: Thanks!

Comment: Wow! I can't believe there's something that Eclipse is better at compared to IntelliJ! Just kidding...I recently started using Android Studio and, while I like many features from it, I miss a couple (like the Problems view) from Eclipse...

Comment: I'm with you Jonathan, I also miss the problems view. Maybe it's just a matter of getting used to it. Free Android Studio was really a smart move by the IntelliJ folks... it seems like it's finally getting many of us stubborn Eclipse devs to give something else a try.

Comment: Actually, Android Studio has a problems scope, it is located on the project tab, in the dropdown in the top left corner. The "problem" is (pun intended), it never shows anything for me. Its maybe just a defining scope for common actions for groups of files (like "find usages" or similar). EDIT: it shows files with problems after a "make", but not a list of problems like in Eclipse.

Comment: Well, even if the code compiles, there can be a lot other lint problems.
Just run an Inspection!
You will see a very good overview of all your problems, you can do this by open the command input with the hotkey CMD+SHIFT+A or CONTROL+SHIFT+A and then enter "Inspect"

Comment: For Android studio please check the answer @ link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099969/how-to-implement-unimplemented-methods-to-all-child-classes-in-eclipse/42382559#42382559